# How to extract page name and authToken from url using express get route in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I have URL like this : `http://localhost:3000/pageName` and I am setting my express route like below:

```
app.get("/:pageName",(req,res)=>{
if (authentication === true) {
   res.render(req.param.pageName}
})
```

Above works fine when it gets `http://localhost:3000/demo`.

However, when it gets this type of URL : `http://localhost:3000/pageName/authToken` like:

`http://localhost:3000/demo/ubawfei346876jhat78gw8898ig8837yr`

Route says cannot get `demo/ubawfei346876jhat78gw8898ig8837yr` and when I changed above code to this :

```
app.get("/:pageName/: authToken",(req,res) => { 
   if(authentication===true{
       res.render(req.param.pageName}
   )}
```

Then this type of url works fine :
`http://localhost:3000/demo/ubawfei346876jhat78gw8898ig8837yr`

But this type of URL : `http://localhost:3000/demo` is not working anymore

I would like to implement something like this when url is something like this

`http://localhost:3000/demo` then it should redirect to:

`req.params.pageName`

And when url looks like this `http://localhost:3000/demo/yeieyhsi736hdh` then it should varify token if varified redirect to:

`req.params.pageName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your url like this `http://localhost:3000/demo?token=As3ferrfmi5jr4jr4btdth54y6y6rty34t45t5y666666`

```
app.get('/:pageName', (req, res) => {
  //you can check if pageName is correct or not
  if (req.query.token != undefined) {
    const token = req.query.token;
    // we must use strong secret, I am using "secret" for demo
    jwt.verify(token,"secret", (err,data) => {
      if (err) {
        //do something if error occurs
      } else {
        // you can also do something with data which was stored on your token
        res.render(req.params.pageName);
      }
    })
  } else if (authenticate) {
    // do something for authentication to access this else if
    res.render(req.params.pageName);
  } else {
    // you can also render some error page or send 404 status
    res.send('Something went wrong!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement both routes, and if an `authToken` is provided, then run a check on the `authToken`.

However, the way you are doing it right now would cause an endless redirect, as when any request to your `/:pageName` is made, it would be redirected to itself, so you need to provide a `response` with your content from within the route, not a `redirect`.

```js
app.get("/:pageName", (req, res) => {
  if (authentication) {
    let pageName = req.params.pageName;
    //Retrieve something with pageName and send it;
    res.send(pageName);
  } else {
    res.send("Not authorised");
  }
})

app.get("/:pageName/:authToken", (req, res) => {
  let authToken = req.params.authToken;
  if (isGood(authToken) && authentication) { //Fictious authToken check
    let pageName = req.params.pageName;
      //Retrieve something with pageName and send it;
      res.send(pageName);
  } else {
  res.send("Not authorised");
  }
})
```

Comment: bro actually it is `res.render(req.params.pageName)` sorry for miss typing and thanks.